# Mandatory filed on page layout is not working on e.force:createRecord event

Tags: lightning

Can anyone please help me why one of my custom fields which is required on Page Layout is not giving any error while saving a record via e.force:createRecord event on Case object.

Thanks

Comment: does record get saved? Or it does not get saved without an error?

Comment: Hi Sanket, It get saved. but it shouldn't.